# Frigidaire gas oven doesn’t reach set temp

Tags: gas, oven

For several months the gas oven has had delayed ignition - sound of small explosion (thump) after turning the oven on.  I use the term delayed because it takes notably longer to ignite the gas and it is a larger thump than it used to be.

More recently, the oven struggled to reach the set temperature.  After 20-30 minutes, I turned on the convection oven switch and it heated up better.

The past couple nights the oven has been working fine.

Gas burners on the stove work fine.

Ed

Comment: Look for plugged nozzles in the burner head. Could be something in the oven dripped on it.

Comment: Not heating up and taking a longer time to ignite is not good.  There are enough youtube videos of exploding house to see what happens when gas is not ignited fast enough.  Not heating up fast might be a sign of poor burning which causes CO gas which causes death.  Have it checked out now before using.

Comment: I'd concur. If you're comfortable disassembling, checking, and reconnecting gas parts in the oven, do so now. If not (and there's no shame in that - electrical starts fires that burn your house down fairly slowly, gas errors cause _BOOM_ that can take out the neighborhood _NOW_), get a pro in to check it out.

Comment: Natural gas, or propane?  If natural gas, are you smelling unburned fuel (a very distinctive odor)?  How is the burner ignited?  Pilot light, or electric igniter?